# Problems in creating vm from shared image in Azure

Tags: terraform, virtual-machine, azure-rm

**Cross posted in HashiCorp Forum: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/problems-in-creating-vm-from-shared-image/52437**

Here is the code I am using for creating a Windows VM from Shared Image gallery:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name                  = "myvm" 
  location              = "East US"
  resource_group_name   = "MyResGroup"
  vm_size               = "Standard_D4as_v5"

  network_interface_ids =  [azurerm_network_interface.nic.id]

  storage_image_reference {
    id = "/subscriptions/4a4.....673/resourceGroups/rg-vm-images/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/vmsgallary/images/testvmimage"
  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name               = "my_os_storage_disk"
    caching            = "ReadWrite"
    create_option      = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type  = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "myvm"
    admin_username = "azureuser"
    admin_password = "MyComplexPassword"
  }

  os_profile_windows_config {
  }
}
```

It gives the following error (after 40/50 mins or so):

```
OS Provisioning for VM ‘xxx’ did not finish in the allotted time. However, the VM guest agent was detected running. This suggests the guest OS has not been properly prepared to be used as a VM image (with CreateOption=FromImage). To resolve this issue, either use the VHD as is with CreateOption=Attach or prepare it properly for use as an image:
    
    Instructions for Windows: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-upload-image/
    Instructions for Linux: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image/
    Deleting and recreating the virtual machine may resolve the issue.
```

Here is the information of the shared image:
[image]

OS type: Windows
OS state: Generalized

[image]

Note that I have been successful in creating a Linux VM using the same code (except those that are only applicable to Linux).

terraform version: 1.3.9
azurerm provider: 3.46.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following where I can create windows VM successfully:

I have used  `resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine"`

```
resource "azurerm_shared_image_gallery" "example" {
  name                = "exampleimagegallery"
   resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = "eastus"
  description         = "Shared images and things."

  tags = {
    Hello = "There"
    World = "Example"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_shared_image" "example" {
  name                = "kavyamyimage"
  gallery_name        = azurerm_shared_image_gallery.example.name
   resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = "eastus"
  os_type             = "Windows"

  identifier {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2016-Datacenter"
  }


data "azurerm_shared_image" "existing" {
  name                = "kavyamyimage"
  gallery_name        = azurerm_shared_image_gallery.example.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}


output "sharedimageid" {
  value = data.azurerm_shared_image.existing.id
}
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  name                = "kaexample-nic"
 location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "example-ip-config"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "kaexample-virtual-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "kkexample-subnet"
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.0.0/24"]
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}


First I executed above with terraform apply and then deployed as below, as the vm required shared image to be created prior and if they are parallelly trying to be created and the vm depends on image creation , there will be conflicts.

Else, add depends _on parameter to the resource block such that VM that depends on image creation first .

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                = "example-machine"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = "eastus"
  size                = "Standard_F2"
  admin_username      = "adminuser"
  admin_password      = "P@$$w0rd1234!"
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.example.id,
  ]
  

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2016-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  //source_image_id = data.azurerm_shared_image.existing.id
 depends_on = [
    data.azurerm_shared_image.existing
  ]
  
}
```

[image]

[image]

**Reference:** [azurerm_virtual_machine | terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine#os_profile_windows_config)

Comment: Thank you you verifying the information for me. Our problem seems to be related to the activity of virus and malware scanning agent running on the system. We think CPU spiking near 90 to 100% was due to the initial scanning of the disks. However 40+ mins seems a bit high for scanning around 100 to 200 GB of hard disk.